# Missing parameters interface Android

Tags: android, parameters, interface, geolocation

I'm using a interface in my code like this:

```
public interface OnSetListener {
    void onInitShift(long datetime, double lat, double lon);

    void onFinishShift(long datetime, double lat, double lon, String comments);

    void onChangeToPause(long datetime, String reason_id, String description, double lat, double lon);

    void onChangeToMove(long datetime, String vehicle, String pk_vehicle, double lat, double lon);

    void onReturnToWork(long datetime, double lat, double lon);
}
```

I call the first method using this line and I can guarantee 100% that it has the right values at this point, because I debug it.

```
_callback.onInitShift(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() , my_location.getLatitude(), my_location.getLongitude());
```

Here is were I implement the interface:

```
f_status.setOnSetListener(new FragmentChangeUserActivity.OnSetListener()) {
    @Override
    public void onInitShift(long datetime, double lat, double lon) { 
        String user = app_data_db.getAppUserCompleteName(_userSQLiteID);
....
```

The problem is that, for some reason, I'm only receiving the parameter **datetime** and **lat**, the **lon** parameter appears to be missing and doesn't have any value although I debug the code, and **my_location.getLongitude()** has value.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

```
private LocationListener ll_check_coords = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        my_location = location;
 ....
```

This is the method were i get the location and using it in the variable **my_location**

Comment: What is type of my_location object ? Maybe the getLongitude() method return incorrect value.

Comment: Is a variable of type Location. Like i said in the text the method getLongitude() receives the correct value. I don't know why they are not passing to the implementation of the interface :/

Comment: Can you add your code when you try to get the my_location object ?

Comment: @Johann67, i added the respective method. Thanks :)

Comment: OK, and you call your method in the LocationListener or 
in another part of your code ?

Comment: Anoter part. This locationListener it's only used to get the current location.
I use the locationListener in this line **lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 0, ll_check_coords);**

Since the lm corresponds to the LocationManager

Comment: Maybe is because my_location object is not updated by the LocationManager. Where you are in debug mode, the executation was slower, it's why the my_location object is correctly initialized here. Try to use your object only after onLocationChanged.

Comment: But when i make **my_location.getLatitude()** and **my_location.getLongitude()** it has the correct values. Just when it enters the method it only have the first 2 parameters.